# How can I speed up the search on a file of about 2 GB in C under Linux

Tags: c, linux, full-text-search, large-files, memory-mapped-files

I'm developing a C program under Linux which make a search on file which is large ~2GB.
The file consists of text rows terminated by `'\n'`, each row consists of five fields `'|'`  separated like a|b|c|d|e|.

Then i need to parse every row to accomplish the search.
The file is sorted by the field a, but the search is done, mainly, using field b and c as search keys !

I tried to use `mapped file` to speed up the search trough the file, but I did not get satisfactory results,
mainly - i think - for the reasons explained above.

Now I think to use an array, in which I insert the data already parsed in the struct, then I sort the array by
the fields b and c and the apply binary search only if the search keys are b and c, otherwise I use a sequential search.

Is it useful to use mapped memory to fill an array from a sequential file ?

Is it a good way to improve research?

Any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: If you're doing this a lot, consider importing the file into a SQL database with appropriate indexes. Or even create extra index files yourself that refer to locations in the main one.

Comment: If using memory mapped files, [`posix_madvise()`](http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_madvise.3.html) might help by letting you tell the os about your intended usage pattern.

Comment: @Shawn as long as possible I would like to avoid using another database besides the one I already use, Informix. I can't upload the file to Informix because of the little free space left.